# Is it possible to move a boost::optional?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, move-semantics, boost-optional

I've been trying to define a defaulted move constructor in a class with a `boost::optional` member variable.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct bar {std::vector<int> vec;};

struct foo {
  foo() = default;
  foo(foo&&) = default;
  boost::optional<bar> hello;
};

int main() {
  foo a;
  foo b(std::move(a));
}
```

My compiler supports both move semantics and defaulted move constructors, but I cannot get this to work.

> ```
> % clang++ foo.cc -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
> foo.cc:15:7: error: call to deleted constructor of 'foo'
>   foo b(std::move(a));
>       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
> foo.cc:9:3: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
>   foo(foo&&) = default;
>   ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

Is there a way to move a `boost::optional` *without* modifying Boost's source code? Or should I wait until Boost supports moving?

I had the same problem with `boost::any` in the past.

Comment: Someone in #boost pointed me to this: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/1841

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at `boost::optional` source code, it doesn't define move constructors or move assignments. However, it does define copy constructor and assignment, which prevent the compiler from auto-generating move constructor and assignment for it.

See [Move constructor — Q&A](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/move-constructor-qa/):

> the compiler will implicitly generate move constructor as member-wise moves, unless you have explicitly defined a copy constructor or copy/move assignment or a destructor

As Luc Danton suggests there needs to be a cure for that. Let's try using `swap` to move `boost::optional` in the hope that creating an empty `boost::optional` is cheap and then we just swap the default-constructed `boost::optional` with the one from the r-value `foo`, e.g.:

```
foo(foo&& b) {
    hello.swap(b.hello);
}
```

And same for the move assignment.

Comment: That is a correct diagnostic, but you need a cure to make this answer complete!

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate. I could write a wrapper class that supports moving by using `std::swap`, and implicit conversion to `boost::optional`. I hope this will be fixed in the/a next version of Boost.

Answer (score 24):

Boost.Optional supports move construction only since Boost version 1.56. See [the release notes](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_56_0.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear how high on the agenda C++11 feature support for boost::optional is.

I found a nice fellow on the Internet who gave me some of his own code under a boost license...which is still undergoing some tweaks.  It's at a point where it works for me.  Maybe it will help anyone looking at this question:

https://github.com/hostilefork/CopyMoveConstrainedOptional

There is also a larger group effort to define a `std::optional` which has been going on...but their reference implementation wasn't able to handle some of the cases I had:

http://kojot.sggw.waw.pl/~akrzemi1/optional/tr2.optional.proposal.html